# Skip first line using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fil) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a statement like:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
      ...
}
```

which causes me error as there is a header in the underlying .csv file. I want to skip this row, but when I use:

```
string [] lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Skip(1).ToArray();
```

yields me that `String` cannot use `Skip(1)`. The same thing when I try to use:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

yields me the same error.

Does anyone have any idea? Can I adjust the `Foreach` loop to become a `For` loop where I dismiss the first row?

Regards,

> EDIT

The code I use as of now is:

```
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();

   foreach (string line in lines)
    {
            var cols = line.Split(';');
            if (cols.Length == 1)
                continue;
            DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
            dr[0] = file;
            for (int cIndex = 1; cIndex + 1 < tbl.Columns.Count; cIndex++)
            {
                dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
            }
    }
    System.Text.StringBuilder b = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn c in tbl.Columns)
        {
            b.Append(c.ColumnName.ToString() + ":" + r[c.ColumnName].ToString());
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
    return tbl;
```

here the b.ToString() returns Nothing (as in NULL). Earlier when I used the GetAllLines() it returned:

fileName:fileNameStore:storeQuantity:quantityfileName:fileNameStore:1000Quantity:30

and it goes on like that.

My ideas are that perhaps I've made it so that I only imported one big long string, so when I skip the first line, it gets NULL.

But this is my first C# code ever, so I'm having some difficulties figuring this out.

Comment: Why don't you just use `StreamReader` and just call `reader.ReadLine()` first to ignore the first line and then process every other lines ?

Comment: are you sure you have added reference to System.Linq namespace ?

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadLines(file)` does NOT return 1 string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

there is no problem with your current algorithm:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

just ensure you import the namespace below.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Using this technique I recently found out that my table will return as NULL. Earlier it was a "full" table, with the first row being the header. Any idea?

Comment: @Cenderze can you update your answer with the error log?

Comment: I receive no error, but the code I use in order to create a datatable returns a NULL table. I can edit the code I use in a couple of minutes. Thanks for rewieving the issue.

Comment: @Cenderze sure. no problem.

Comment: I've updated the OP now, with an idea of what may be wrong, which I've tried to Google the solution for at least.

Comment: @Cenderze okay i will have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139176/discussion-between-ousmane-mahy-diaw-and-cenderze).

Answer (score 7):

I would use the [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `File.ReadAllLines()`.Because it is lazy loading the file. U'd rather not use the `.ToArray()` or the `.ToList()` as it would **persist the whole file** into the memory.

This will stream the data.

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file).Skip(1))
{

}
```

Will do the job...

Answer (score 4):

Okay so extending my comment with some code sample and more descriptive explanation. I would suggest you to use `StreamReader` :

```
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)) )
{
```

Now ignore first line :

```
    reader.ReadLine();
```

And proceed with your reading logic :

```
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ( ( line =  reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

If you need to *"pack"* these lines into array you can just create a `List<string>` at the beginning and inside your logic use `List<string>.Add(string)` method with `line` as your string parameter. Then you can use `List<string>.ToArray()` method to return array of lines.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved by a single of code as:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(csv_file_path).Skip(1).Select(a => a.Split(';',',')).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is very neat with a single line of code!

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this, its not pretty but it will work :)

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
bool first = true;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if(!first)
    {
       ...
    }
    first = false;
}
```